# What's the purpose of a pump on water heatr inlet?

Tags: water-heater

Our water heater has an electric pump on its inlet. During a recent service call on the water heater the technician said it was a good thing. What is not clear is the pump's contribution. Especially now, after the technician replaced the gas valve and the much longer delay in getting hot water on the far side of the house. Any chance it's due to a failed pump? Pump photo below.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is on the inlet(the cold water)?

Comment: Actually, no. What is true is there are three pipe connections at the water heater. The connection for the pump feels cold at its shutoff valve, but it is connected to the hot water outlet. So it appears that it pumps cold water.

Comment: Think it might be a circulating pump on a hot water loop to far taps so the hot water does not need to go as much for hot water to come out of the tap.  It might be on the return section so the water would be cooler.

Comment: I realize now that is most likely the case. Any idea on how to test it (assuming that it would be useful to know)? All I can tell is that it gets power - circuit tester says it's hot.

Answer (score 1):

It's presumably for recirculating hot water to reduce delay time for hot water far away from the heater.

There are a variety of schemes for this, and which one is employed here is not obvious from the picture. Some have dedicated hot water recirculation return lines, most retro-fitted ones return water via the cold water lines with a check valve, and control logic may include a timer and/or temperature sensors (clever logic may even include motion sensors - no recirculation when there's no activity in the house, recirculate when people are present and moving around.)

- If the timer (if used) is not set correctly the pump may be running
  at times when you're unlikely to use hot water and notice it working.
- If other sensors are defective or not connected things may not work
  right.
- If the check valve is not working cold water can be fed into the hot
  lines where that is (usually the farthest hot fixture from the
  heater.)
- Or it may, in fact, be the pump not working. Which could be "failed" or could be "power shut off" for instance.

Comment: If in a hard water area, the pump could also just be blocked with hard water deposits.  Disassembly and cleaning might help.

Comment: I've discovered pump is a Taco model 003-BC4 "cartridge circulator". It is possible to replace the cartridge but there seems to be no way to find out if it's necessary.